# Is it safe to recharge 5v power bank from Raspberry Pi Pico VBUS?

Tags: pi-pico

My project uses a small 5v power bank to power my RPP. Rather than adding a USB socket for recharging the power bank, I would like to use the existing one on the Pico, connecting the VBUS pin to the charging input of the power bank.

My understanding of the RPP power circuit is that VBUS is connected directly to the USB port so this should not overload the RPP.

Would this work?

Comment: But your charging input might be much higher that 5V.

Comment: I was planning to plug a standard 5V wall charger into the RPP USB socket. Wouldn't that just be the same voltage as it would be if I'd plugged it directly into the poer bank?

Comment: Ah, 5V wall warts usually are higher than 5V, say 5.5V or higher. Cheap one may be 6V. So there is a risk.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find any information regarding the tracks used between VBUS and the USB socket.  I suppose drawing half an amp or so would be safe.

As pointed out in the comments VBUS is unregulated.  Whatever voltage is present on USB pin 1 will be present on VBUS.